# How to use Vertex Groups to determine the distribution of an object in geometry nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, geometry-nodes

I am using the new Geometry Nodes to put chocolate chips on a cookie. I have weight painted the cookie shape to keep the chocolate chips on the top of the cookie.

If the vertex group is named "Distribution", how would I reference this to keep the geometry nodes (choc chips) on the top of the cookie?

Comment: what do you mean by "how would I reference this"? If you want the particles to appear only on the vertex group, choose it in the Point Distribute > Density field

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you want the particles to appear only on the vertex group, choose it in the *Point Distribute > Density* field:

[image]

Comment: is it possible to make this Vertex Group a NodeTree Input in the Modifier tab, so I can reuse my scattering tool with different objects and different given vertex groups? ... When I tried so, nothing will be scattered

Comment: @ Marten Zander, hello, sorry I tried a bit so I was able to answer to this question but I'm not good with Geometry Nodes  :/  maybe ask the question?